# Changing vertex array in ThreeJs using BufferGeometry

Tags: javascript, three.js, buffer-geometry

so - I have a situation where I'm filling the screen with calculated polygons.  The polygons are constantly changing shape - ie the number of vertices is changing each frame.  If I create a new geometry each frame - suddenly my machine effectively halts and I'm apparently sucking heaps of memory - it seems that I have to change the buffers in a geometry.

So I've tried using bufferGeometry, and basically doing:

```
var position = asBuffer.attributes.position;
position.array[0] = changedValue;
position.needsUpdate = true;
```

in my render loop - but it doesn't seem to work at all.  If I use just a normal geometry, it *will* dynamically chnage - if I set needsUpdate - but only if I change the values in the original vectors.  If I change the arrays themselves - it doesn't seem to show up.

I've got an example of all of this here: http://jsbin.com/fanebah/edit?js,console,output - if you swap the lines that create the "cube" - it goes from working to not working.

I'd prefer to use bufferGeometry - it's faster and closer to the way I'm producing the data - What am I doing wrong?   Or does threejs just not support dynamic buffergeometry?

Comment: Your code works. Try  position.array[ 10 ] = oldValue;

Comment: Thankyou! obviously the buffer wasn't shaped as I expected.  Appreciate you looking at it

Comment: Maybe you can answer this question and mark it solved. Otherwise I'd suggest you delete it.